# Navigate to page on Server from Blazor WebAssembly in Hosted Solution

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have a Blazor WebAssembly Hosted Solution using the built in Identity. I have scaffolded out the Identity views which are in the Server project (Areas/Identity/Pages/Account).

When in the Blazor Client WebAssembly project I have a link that will navigate to Manage the account

```
<NavLink class="nav-link sideMenu-nav-item-link" href="authentication/profile">Account - @context.User.Identity.Name</NavLink>
```

So this calls the Authentication component which contains the RemoteAuthenticatorView

```
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action">
    <LoggingIn>
        <Loading />
    </LoggingIn>
    <CompletingLoggingIn>
        <Loading />
    </CompletingLoggingIn>
    <LogOutSucceeded>
        <RedirectToHome />
    </LogOutSucceeded>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>
```

So the action passed is profile.  How does RemoteAuthenticatorView know where to route on the Server?  I want to add some additional pages like Subscription to the Server where the user can manage their subscription.  How can I navigate from the Blazor WebAssembly to a page on the Server? Will it go through the RemoteAuthenticatorView?

Comment: They don't make it very clear but this should get you going down the correct path: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-app-routes. Specifically look at the `builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization` code example just below all the routes.

Comment: One more thing..if you want to change the *default Identity* paths, look at `AuthenticationPaths.RemoteProfilePath`